# Mapping a thread number to a (non sequential) position in an array

Tags: c++, cuda, formula

I would like to map a thread_id.  This in C/CUDA but it is more an algebraic problem that I am trying to solve.

So the mapping I am trying to achieve is along the lines:

- Threads 0-15: read value array[0]
- Threads 16-31: read value [3]
- Threads 32-47: read value [0]
- Threads 48-63: read value [3]
- Threads  64-79: read value array[6]
- Threads  80-95: read value array[9]
- Threads  96-111: read value array[6]
- Threads  112-127: read value array[9]

and so on..

Note this is a simplification of the mapping, in reality there are more than 128 threads but the sequence is as shown and threads would always map to a multiple of three.

**What formula can I use that each thread can run to find out what array position it should look at?**

I would like to use some kind of formula as I have in the following example and not an explicit map or any if-statements.

To illustrate how I have solved this for a different case which required a different mapping, i.e.:

- Threads  0-31: read value array[0]
- Threads  32-63: read value [3]

I used the code

```
rintf(float(tid)/96.0)*3
```

Comment: Personally I can't find any question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work in C:

```
3 * ((n>>4 & 1) + (n>>5 & ~1))
```

where `n` is the thread number.

I made the assumption here that the pattern continues beyond 128 as: 0,3,0,3,6,9,6,9,12,15,12,15,etc.

**Edit:**

This form, without bitwise operations, may be easier to understand:

```
6 * (n/64) + 3 * ((n/16) % 2)
```

It will give the same results. `n` is assumed to be an integer, so that division will round down.

Comment: Apologies, I did look at the posted answers and appreciate the answers.  I am not sure how your solution is working.

Comment: I added a simpler version. Let me know if it needs clarification.

Comment: In the first example with bitwise operations you should not have the `& 1` applied to the `n>>4` since that will make the sequence 0,3,0,3,6,9,6,9 repeat rather than continue. +1 in any case.

Comment: @Tom: It's the second part of the expression that makes it continue rather than repeat. I tested it and it works correctly.

Comment: My mistake, I'm an idiot! I actually have no idea what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
int f(int thread_id)
{
    int tmp = thread_id % 64;
    int tmp2 = thread_id / 64;
    if (tmp =< 15 || (tmp >= 32 && tmp <= 47))  {
         return tmp2 * 6;
    } else {
         return tmp2 * 6 + 3;
    }
}
```